Angular - promise keeps returning ZoneAwarePromise
How would I get the myPromise to be a normal promise instead of a ZoneAwarePromise? I've also unsuccessfully tried wrapping the resolve() in a NgZone.runOutsideAngular() and a setTimeout().
const myPromise = Promise.resolve('');
console.log('myPromise', myPromise); // logged as ZoneAwarePromise


Just a note, setTimeout and setInterval both trigger zone updates

We need to see more code, the zone works fine for me with a promise.

Angular requires zone.js to patch Promise, so if the Promise is not ZoneAwarePromise, Angular will throw an error. You can disable other async tasks like setTimeout, but not Promise
If you disable promise in angular app it will throw below error.
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.

List of API that can be disabled

I didn't know you could disable these.

@GetOffMyLawn Glad you found it useful!
